# Populate cURL script $url with input value

Tags: php, forms, curl

I have a form template that I am using. I process the form and send the data using cURL. The endpoint for submission varies from form to form, so I tried putting it in a var on the page, populating a hidden input with the value and submitting that way. It only works if I hardcode the `$url` var in the cURL script. I am populating other fields with the `$_POST` value for inputs, not sure why it's not working.

On the actual form page I have it set up like this:

```
<?php
    $inf_endpoint = 'http://someuniqueurl.com';
?>
<html>
    <body>
         <form ...>
             <input type="hidden" id="inf_endpoint" name="inf_endpoint" value="<?php echo $inf_endpoint ?>" />
         </form>
     </body>
 </html>
```

And in the processor/cURL script

```
<?php
    $url = $_POST['inf_endpoint'];
    //other field and curl stuff
    $ch = curl_init($url);
?>
```

It never submits like this, I have to hardcode the `$url` value. I have tried `$_POST` and `$_GET` to no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: your given url is not valid.

Comment: Should have corrected that in my code, my bad. But issue still remains, cannot set the $url value as a hidden input on a per form basis

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
<?php
    //$inf_endpoint = 'http://someuniqueurl.com';
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $url=$_POST['inf_endpoint'];
        //$url='https://www.google.com/';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if($result === false){
            echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        echo($result);
    }

?>
```

Chang you html to this

```
<html>
    <body>
         <form action="" methode="post">
             <input type="url" id="inf_endpoint" name="inf_endpoint" value="" />
             <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
         </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That still has a hardcoded $url value, I want to us the same processor to process templated forms, which will have a different $url value